# Can't talk to HBase from different kubernetes namespace: java.net.UnknownHostException: hregion-0.hregion

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using kubernetes, where I have a Hadoop cluster running in namespace 'platform'.
I have an example application running in namespace 'example'
The example application needs to talk to HBase.  When it does so, we see the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: hregion-0.hregion
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionUtils.getStubKey(ConnectionUtils.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getClient(ConnectionImplementation.java:1192)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientServiceCallable.setStubByServiceName(ClientServiceCallable.java:44)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:386)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.getTableState(MetaTableAccessor.java:1078)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:403)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:445)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallable.call(RpcRetryingCallable.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3084)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3076)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:442)
```

The command

```
> nslookup hregion-0.hregion
```

on the client machine fails, because the `hregion` service is in the `platform` namespace (where that command will succeed).

We suspected that the HBase region server has registered itself with zookeeper using an incomplete name, and verified by connecting to the zookeeper server:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 8] ls /hbase/rs
[hregion-0.hregion,16020,1560851357442]
```

The `ConnectionUtils.getStubKey` method simply uses `java.net.InetAddress.getByName(hostname)` and it is this method which fails.

Here is some zookeeper debugging info (this from the HBase master):

```
hbase(main):001:0> zk_dump
HBase is rooted at /hbase
Active master address: hmaster-0.hmaster.platform.svc.cluster.local,16000,1560851357485
Backup master addresses:
Region server holding hbase:meta: hregion-0.hregion,16020,1560851357442
Region servers:
 hregion-0.hregion,16020,1560851357442
```

On the `hregion-0` server, we have the following entries in `/etc/hosts`:

```
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.1.14.53      hregion-0.hregion.platform.svc.cluster.local    hregion-0
```

And the `/etc/resolv.conf` file looks like this:

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search platform.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local mycompany.com
options ndots:5
```

How do I fix this?  I assume I need to tell HBase to register its nodes in zookeeper using their fully qualified domain name - how?

Comment: Did you reflect the desired host names in /etc/hosts on region servers master?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the contents of /etc/hosts on the region server - I assume that's what you're referring to.

Comment: not sure how things would work with kubernetes, but in normal environment just have one key-value pair with the value being the host name you actually want to be used. Otherwise things will get confused.

Comment: Note that neither of the entries in /etc/hosts are what is actually being used by the client.

Comment: Well the client should just be accessing the zookeeper quorum (assuming that each zookeeper is separate from each region server). But each zookeeper should have the right host names in its respective /etc/hosts. Right? If it's all in synch then I can't suggest anything else. Probably kubernetes-related which is not my depth